# SAT $O(\log n)$ SAT oracle queries?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, turing-machines

Let SAT be the set of all satisfiable boolean formulae.

Can there exists an algorithm A which can actually computes a satisfying assignment for a boolean formula of size
n using only $O(\log n)$ SAT oracle queries? Prove or disprove.

You can assume that NP $\neq $ P in your proof.

Comment: Do you have any ideas, or attempts at solving the problem that you'd like to share?  Perhaps you are stuck somewhere.  One way to get unstuck is to refer to definitions.  Also, it might help us to know the source of the question.

Comment: @Kalpish If you want us to help you, please, give more details, including -— especially — your own thoughts.